# Display YoutubeThumbnil and onclick play Video on same view in List

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I know I am asking stupid question, thanks a lot for help from you guy

If any one can give me idea how to display youtubethumbnil in listview and once user click on the thumbnil then it should play in listview only

I have seen Android YouTube Api

I am getting thumbnil url from server

```
<LinearLayout>
   <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I can use frameLayout and inside that I can put YouTubeThumbnailView and YouTubePlayerView

But I am damn sure there is very simple way to do this

I am using Custom Cursor Adapter

Please help me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical">

   <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview"
                android:layout_width="0"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
                android:layout_width="0"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The trick is to put them in a LinearLayout which has vertical orientation. And then we need to give the width zero and weight one to each so that they take half screen.

Comment: I am using this in custom cursor adapter , is it fine and it says it accepts only video id , can we pass complete URL at the place of video id ?

Comment: This post was about placing them next to each other. For the next one that you commented here please create a new question. This will help others to get the answer as well. Thank you